# Custom serialization in Service Stack using DeSerializeFn

Tags: json, servicestack

In servicestack, I am trying to process a webhook which sends the following JSON body to a service stack endpoint:

```
{
"action": "actionType1",
"api_version": "1.00",
"data": {
    "id": "a8d316b8-10a7-4440-a836-9bd354f656db",
          //VARIABLE other properties / structure
    }
}
```

Which I am trying to map to the following request object:

```
[Route("/public/Webhookhandler", HttpVerbs.Post)]
public class MyCustomRequst
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string api_version { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }  //Will be the remaining JSON
}
```

However, when the service stack framework processes this - the value in "data" is the correct part of the JSON body, but with all of the quotes removed - so it is no longer valid.

I have tried to override the serialization for the whole request object using something like this:

```
JsConfig<MyCustomRequst>.DeSerializeFn = DeserializeMyRequestDto;


public MyCustomRequst DeserializeMyRequestDto(string rawBody)
{
    var result = rawBody.FromJson<MyCustomRequst>();
    return result
}
```

But even in this case, the value of the "rawBody" variable is still the correct JSON data but with all the quotes removed, e.g.

```
{
  action:actionType1,
  api_version:1.00,
  data:{id:a8d316b8-10a7-4440-a836-9bd354f656db}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  I am unsure whether I am trying to make service stack do something it is not intended to do, or whether I am missing something that would make this work.

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: This question is very unclear on what the issue is, what's causing it and what answer you're expecting. I'd consider completely rephrasing it showing the source code that causes the issue, the end result you want to get and what you've tried. Make it clear how you got the invalid JSON as that needs to be the first thing you try to solve since JSON serializers need valid JSON. When asking questions focus on source code with goal of reproducibility not superfluous description which just detracts from identifying the issue and preferred solution.

Comment: I appreciate the comment and the time - and I have tried to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DTO should closely match the shape of the JSON, if it's always a flat object you can use a string Dictionary, e.g:

```
[Route("/public/Webhookhandler", HttpVerbs.Post)]
public class MyCustomRequst
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string api_version { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> data { get; set; } 
}
```

If it's a more nested object structure you can use a `JsonObject` for a more flexible API to parse dynamically.

Comment: Thanks Mythz - that was exactly what was needed and solved the issue.  I was not aware of the JSONObject - so must have been looking in the wrong places!